# Setting up JDK 7 for IntelliJ on the Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, java

I installed the JDK by downloading the dmg from the Oracle website here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u9-downloads-1859576.html

After installation I tried to setup the JDK in IntelliJ but when I set the location to the JDK in the Project Structure->SDKs screen, only a few libraries were loaded and many (including all libraries from Content/Classes/) were missing.

How can I add all of the necessary libraries?

The install location for the JDK is **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home**

I've tried looking in **/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/** to no avail.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Under `Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs`.

By using '+' sign, you should add a valid JDK, that will take care and add the proper libraries, eg. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-XYZ.jdk/Contents/Home`

### [image: Project Structure -> PlatformSettings -> SDKs]

For jdk images older, like 1.6 or before, you need to ensure that all the jars from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkXYZ_VERSION.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib` directory too (charsets.jar, jce.jar, JObjC.jar, jsse.jar, management-agent.jar, resources.jar and rt.jar) are part of your setup.

Comment: bradrox's solution is easier compared to this.

Comment: @Dhanesh it's the same solution, if the content of your jdk install folder is the proper one. Here I presented what was missing in OP's install.

Comment: I think neither the question nor the solution is useful for someone trying to figure out how to configure JDK as SDK in intelliJ. This seems like an one-off issue with someone's JDK installation or specific version of intelliJ unless I am missing something. I do get all jars from jre/lib directory correctly.

Answer (score 67):

Navigate to Project Structure -> Platform Settings/SDKs.

Hit the '+' sign and add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: I have: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`  but the JavaVirtualMachine is empty?

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to select Project Structure->Platform Setting->Global Libraries and click on the "+" icon that is at the top of the middle pane of the Project Structure window.  This brings up a "New Global Library" drop down menu.  From there I was able to locate the libraries I wanted to include.